# Drupal multiple db prefixes

Tags: mysql, drupal-6, prefix

I have multiple drupal sites running off one MySQL database each using a different $db_prefix.

If I was using different databases I could share data by putting them in an array in settings.php and then calling specific databases as I need them.

Is it possible to this by calling a different $db_prefix?

Answer (score 2):

You can share individual tables across different sites, you can do this by making db_prefix an array like this;

```
$db_prefix = array(
    'default' => 'site_a_',
    'users_roles' => 'site_b_',     
    'role' => 'site_b_',
    'sessions' => 'site_b_',
    'users' => 'site_b_'
);
```

If this was in the settings.php for site A, then it would share it's user_roles, roles, sessions and users tables with site B.

Is this what you're wanting?

Comment: Thanks, i think this might be what I need.

Comment: Thanks, i think this might be what I need. I have 2 sites using the same db each with their own prefix. I want to use all of site A's story posts on Site B